# What is the Geometric Generalised T' Method?

Tags: aes, reference-request, algebraic-attack

[This page](http://www.cryptosystem.net/aes/tools.html) by Nicolas T. Courtois  mentions *Geometric Generalised T' Method*. It is described as

> an advanced geometric algorithm, never published, for finding extra linearly independent equations at a given degree, which would normally be found by Gröbner bases techniques, but at a higher degree(!) with much higher memory and with much higher complexity. So in practice, this algorithm has no competitors in producing such equations on current computers.

The [other page](http://www.cryptosystem.net/aes/) of the same site mentions *T' method* (not geometric and not generalized) as one of the steps of the AES attack and it even says that it is described in several papers (but sadly without any link):

> In general, it is likely that in the future, the best attack on AES will be of the following form:
>   1. Use the equations over GF(256).
>   2. Apply one of the versions of XSL.
>   3. Apply a final step. The so called T' method, described in several papers, may or may not be sufficient.

So, my questions are: What is the T' method? Where it is described? What could be its geometric generalization?

Will be grateful for any reference or clue.

Answer (score 4):

*T' method* was introduced in the paper [Cryptanalysis of Block Ciphers with Overdefined Systems of Equations](https://eprint.iacr.org/2002/044) by Nicolas Courtois and Josef Pieprzyk (see section 6.1 and Appendix E).

It is a part of **XSL** attack on block ciphers (such as Rijndael and Serpent).

During XSL attack cipher is represented as a system of multivariate quadratic polynomials and the goal of *T' method* is to derive more linearly independent equations form it.

Don Coppersmith [criticized](https://www.schneier.com/crypto-gram-0210.html#8) this attack but noted that

> The method has some merit, and is worth investigating, but it does not 
>   break Rijndael as it stands.